# Is this partial template specialization?

Tags: c++

I am trying to understand type function in template metaprogramming trough some examples.
I have created one example that removes the reference from a type.

```
template <class T>
struct remove_reference
{ using type = T; };

template <class T>
struct remove_reference<T&>
{ using type = T; };

int main(){
    typename remove_reference<int&>::type a;
}
```

My question is if this is implemented using partial template specialization of if we call it something else?
I feel it is partial because we have not defined it for a specific type but I also feel it isn't because we have just as many template arguments.
The naming may not be important to understanding type functions but I don't want to teach other people the wrong names if I explain it.

Comment: It is indeed [partial template specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization).

Comment: *"type functions"*. Did you mean *traits*?

Comment: @Jarod42 I though type traits returned a value and type functions returned a type. Is that not correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is partial specialisation, because you have restricted to just things that match the pattern `T&`.

You don't need to have fewer template parameters, you can even have *more*. E.g.

```
template <typename Callable>
struct function_something { ... }; // Any functor type

template <typename Ret, typename Args...>
struct function_something<Ret(Args...)> { ... }; // Specialises free functions

template <typename Class, typename Ret, typename Args...>
struct function_something<Ret(Class::*)(Args...)> { ... }; // Specialises member functions
```

Comment: Interesting to know that more arguments are also possible and have a better grasp on what is and isn't partial specialisation.